# UserControl does not have public property named ContentTemplate

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

This question has been asked a few dozen times before; but has never been solved.

i have an **`UpdatePanel`**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelSetupToolbar" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
      ...           
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

But the *visual page designer* in  Visual Studio (2010 (Professional (Windows (7 (Professional (64-bit)))))) gives the error:

> **Error Creating Control** - UpdatePanelSetupToolbar
>
> Type 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not have a public property named 'ContentTemplate'.

[image]
<sup><sup>*Edit: pretty colors in pretty screenshots are added for pretty effect*</sup></sup>

Now, strictly speaking, that is true: [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol_properties) does **not** have a public property called `ContentTemplate`.

Fortunately my `UpdatePanel` is an **`UpdatePanel`**, and it **does** have a public property named [`'ContentTemplate'`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.contenttemplate.aspx).

So how do i convince Visual Studio that my `UpdatePanel` is an `UpdatePanel`?

### Important additional notes

The code above doesn't actually fail as is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelSetupToolbar" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
      ...           
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It only fails when i have content inside the `...` ContentTemplate:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelSetupToolbar" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <Vista:Toolbar ID="ToolbarSetup" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="bbSetupDays" ToolTip="Specify how many allocations will be available on these selected days"
                    OnClick="bbSetupDays_Click"                                        
                    runat="server">Setup Selected Days</asp:LinkButton>         
                </ContentTemplate>
            </Vista:Toolbar>        
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

- but Visual Studio is not complaining about inner `ToolbarSetup`
- it's complaining about the outer `UpdatePanelSetupToolbar` control

So what's the deal with

> Type '%s' does not have a public property named '%s'.

?

### Unimportant additional notes

The ASP.net web-site compiles, builds, and runs *fine*. It's just the Visual Studio (2010) designer that complains.

So what's the deal with `Type '%s' does not have a public property named '%s'.`?

### Series

This question is one in the ongoing Stackoverflow series, **"Templating user controls"**:

- [How to add a Templating to a UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658053/how-to-add-a-templating-to-a-usercontrol/11700540)
- [How to inherit from Control, rather than UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323303/how-to-inherit-from-control-rather-than-usercontrol)
- [UserControl has IsPostBack, but Control does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321621/usercontrol-has-ispostback-but-control-does-not/12321692)
- [UserControl does not have public property named ContentTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656637/usercontrol-does-not-have-public-property-named-contenttemplate)
- [How do i specify CodeFileBaseClass from web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325192/how-do-i-specify-codefilebaseclass-from-web-config)

Comment: Have you ever taken a look at the temporary/intermediate files ASP.NET generates to see if there's anything unusual about the code that's built which might be causing the designer issues?

Comment: I can't reproduce in Visual Studio 2012.  Most controls that support data binding were updated to allow for strong typing.  I believe a side-effect of that enhancement made this problem go away.  http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new

Comment: @KellyS.French i'll leave it to you to figure out which solution works. The bug is so aggravating i can't stand to look at it anymore. i'd kill for a fix, though.

Answer (score 1):

The update panel is really cool but you really can't make user controls with it.  The good news is you can make asp.net user controls that have a javascript payload by following the same design pattern used to make the updatepanel for the ajaxcontroltoolkit.

I built this back in Mar 2009 because I needed a message box that didn't block the ui.  I followed the design pattern for usercontrols using the ajaxcontroltoolkit.  It has complete source and the VS intelisense works on the javascript.  It's a usercontrol that you just drop on the page and it carries it's own javascript payload that you can ajaxify to your hearts content.  It even works in a data repeater with no modifications.  It was actually accepted as a ajaxcontroltoolkit usercontrol on the website asp.net.

It's free you could put it on github or other repository if you wanted.

http://gosylvester.com/downloads/messagebox.aspx

http://gosylvester.com/blog.aspx?id=55

Answer (score 0):

You should solve this per design.

Put your update panel on a page and make the user control without an update panel.

reason: the update panel is intended to autogenerate clientside scripting for asyncronous postback as you surely know.
The user control is a building block with a self contained functionality encapsulating complexity which should be placeable anywhere without requirements to the context and in this case at least you would need a scriptmanager on the page which instantiates the control.

Comment: What if you had a control with no UI, in my case I have a control that will exclude the contained content from being searched and really has no visible component. It also doesn't use JavaScript. In any case, I still get the same error when I try to enclose an out-of-the-box control within my custom control.