# UserControl has IsPostBack, but Control does not

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

i'm trying to solve a bug in Visual Studio, [the suggestion is to stop using `UserControls` and use `Control` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658053/how-to-add-a-templating-to-a-usercontrol).

So i'm converting all my `UserControl` into just `Control`, e.g.:

```
public partial class Controls_UserManagement_GroupManager : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!IsPostBack)
```

becomes

```
public partial class Controls_UserManagement_GroupManager : System.Web.UI.Control
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!IsPostBack)
```

Except that there is no `Control.IsPostBack`?

How do i replace `UserControl` with `Control`?

### Series

This question is one in the ongoing Stackoverflow series, **"Templating user controls"**:

- [How to add a Templating to a UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658053/how-to-add-a-templating-to-a-usercontrol/11700540)
- [How to inherit from Control, rather than UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323303/how-to-inherit-from-control-rather-than-usercontrol)
- [UserControl has IsPostBack, but Control does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321621/usercontrol-has-ispostback-but-control-does-not/12321692)
- [UserControl does not have public property named ContentTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656637/usercontrol-does-not-have-public-property-named-contenttemplate)
- [How do i specify CodeFileBaseClass from web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325192/how-do-i-specify-codefilebaseclass-from-web-config)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Control` has a `Page` property, which has an `IsPostback` property. This should give you the value you need.

```
public class MyControl : Control{
    protected override void OnInit( EventArgs e ){
        if( this.Page.IsPostBack ){
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page.aspx)