# How to inherit from Control, rather than UserControl?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, controls

I have an ASP.net control that inherits from `UserControl`:

**File 1**:

```
public partial class Controls_AllocationDuplicate : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

**File 2**:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AllocationDuplicate.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_AllocationDuplicate" %>
```

[I need the control to inherit from `Control`, rather than `UserControl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658053/how-to-add-a-templating-to-a-usercontrol):

**File.aspx.cs** *(changed)*:

```
public partial class Controls_AllocationDuplicate : System.Web.UI.Control
```

**File.aspx** *(not changed)*:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AllocationDuplicate.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_AllocationDuplicate" %>
```

When i do this, Visual Studio gives a compile error:

> Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it **extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).**

How can I have my *control* inherit from `Control` rather than `UserControl`?

### Series

This question is one in the ongoing Stackoverflow series, **"Templating user controls"**:

- [How to add a Templating to a UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658053/how-to-add-a-templating-to-a-usercontrol/11700540)
- [How to inherit from Control, rather than UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323303/how-to-inherit-from-control-rather-than-usercontrol)
- [UserControl has IsPostBack, but Control does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321621/usercontrol-has-ispostback-but-control-does-not/12321692)
- [UserControl does not have public property named ContentTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656637/usercontrol-does-not-have-public-property-named-contenttemplate)
- [How do i specify CodeFileBaseClass from web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325192/how-do-i-specify-codefilebaseclass-from-web-config)

Comment: *WHY* do you need to inherit from Control instead of UserControl? That's legitimate of course, but from the link you included, I don't understand what you're trying.

Comment: @aquinas: Because `UserControl` does not have a public property named `ContentTemplate`

Comment: Ahh, it's getting designer support. Understood. Yeah, it's never worked for me either, but then the only time I'm in the Designer is when I go "Oh crap! I accidentally hit the designer button, now I have to wait 5 minutes."

Answer (score 1):

Try inherting from WebControl,then use Register instead of Control.
Similar to this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2748/Building-an-ASP-NET-custom-web-control-a-textbox-a

Answer (score 1):

You try to make a custom control and not a user control in this case you can't use ascx file to hold your design but need to design them pragmatically.