# How do i specify CodeFileBaseClass from web.config?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, templating

i<sup>1</sup> am registering a *user control* `Control` in `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
       <pages validateRequest="false">
          <controls>
              <add src="~/GenericControls/Toolbar.ascx" 
                    tagName="Toolbar" tagPrefix="Vista" />
          </controls>
       </pages>
    </system.web>
<configuration>
```

Now, because my *"user control"* is a `Control`, rather than a `UserControl` (in order to support templating), this causes the Visual Studio error:

> ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that **it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl)**.

The fix for this bug is that you [have to remind Visual Studio that the *control`inherits from`Control`](http://forums.asp.net/t/941553.aspx/1):

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Inherits="University.AspNet.Index"  
      CodeFile="Index.aspx.cs" CodeFileBaseClass="XXXXXX" %>
```

with the super-secret `CodeFileBaseClass` attribute. Except i'm not using a **Page** directive, i'm registering the control **site-wide** in web-config:

```
<add src="~/GenericControls/Toolbar.ascx" 
      tagName="Toolbar" tagPrefix="Vista" />
```

How do i specify `CodeFileBaseClass` from within `web.config`?

### Series

This question is one in the ongoing Stackoverflow series, **"Templating user controls"**:

- [How to add a Templating to a UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658053/how-to-add-a-templating-to-a-usercontrol/11700540)
- [How to inherit from Control, rather than UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323303/how-to-inherit-from-control-rather-than-usercontrol)
- [UserControl has IsPostBack, but Control does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321621/usercontrol-has-ispostback-but-control-does-not/12321692)
- [UserControl does not have public property named ContentTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656637/usercontrol-does-not-have-public-property-named-contenttemplate)
- [How do i specify CodeFileBaseClass from web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325192/how-do-i-specify-codefilebaseclass-from-web-config)

Comment: Out of interest, where is footnote #1, referenced in the first line of your question?!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<system.web>
    <!-- ... -->
    <pages pageBaseType="MyWeb.UI.MyPageBase" />
    <!-- ... -->
</system.web>
```

**Also, Refer below links:**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom/archive/2008/08/22/known-issues-for-asp-net-with-net-3-5-sp1.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1305800.aspx

**Suggested Workarounds**:

If the pageBaseType class (for example, MyBasePage) is not needed for all pages, you can remove it from the web.config file, or

Where pages do require the pageBaseType value, modify the classes in the code-behind files to extend the base type. In the filename.aspx.cs code-behind file, make sure that the class inherits from the pageBaseType that is specified in the web.config file (for example, public partial class CodeFileClass : MyBasePage instead of public partial class CodeFileClass : System.Web.UI.Page).

An alternative workaround will allow you to add the following attribute to your page directive:

```
CodeFileBaseClass="System.Web.UI.Page"
```